# Ionic 1 - Cordova- google-maps : Disappeared buttons on map - only IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, phonegap-plugins

Hi every one i am working with Ionic 1 Angularjs. I published my app using geolocation in the app store in November every thing worked fine, since February if you look at the screen shot, the button zoom item ( + / - ) and all the button suggested by google map are missing.

PS : This happens only with ios in android everything works fine
[[image: screen shot]]

Comment: are you using the googlemaps plugin ? also can you please post your code. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of latest version of Google Maps JavaScript API.

As of May 15 2018, JavaScript API was updated to 3.32(latest).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Now, Temporary solution is below code. Use frozen version of Google Maps JavaScript API.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```